# Elastic Search - Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have a scenario where parent object has nested array of objects like below

```
"properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "integer"
    },
    "schoolProgramAttribute": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "disciplineId": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "programId": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now basically a particular disciplineId can repeat multiple times in the nested array. The requirement is to count all the parent objects for each disciplineId .If I just group by disciplineIds I do not get the correct count and I am not sure how reverse aggregation can help .  When we i try reverse aggregation with parent id , I always get count of 1 and I am not sure I am doing the correct way.

In SQL world it is something like

```
select count(distinct id),DisciplineId from table group by disciplineid
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the aggregation are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

First you should apply nested `terms` aggregation by `disciplineId` and inside it you should add `reverse_nested`

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "nested": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "schoolProrgamAttribute"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "discipline": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "schoolProrgamAttribute.disciplineId"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "parent": {
                            "reverse_nested": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result for `discipline` aggregation will give you number of entries for each `disciplineId` (and it doesn't exclude duplicates inside parent) whereas `parent` will give the desired value - number of parents for each `disciplineId` value

Comment: Sure will try. Thank you